# Parse attributes of root node having namespace in XML

Tags: python, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

I have the following xml which i was trying to parse and wanted to get the value of attributes of root node i.e. `xmlns:n1` value. But i am getting the key error using the following value.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<n1:Level-1C_Tile_ID xmlns:n1="https://psd-12.sentinel2.eo.esa.int/PSD/S2_PDI_Level-1C_Tile_Metadata.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://psd-12.sentinel2.eo.esa.int/PSD/S2_PDI_Level-1C_Tile_Metadata.xsd /dpc/app/s2ipf/FORMAT_METADATA_TILE_L1C/02.10.02/scripts/../../../schemas/02.12.05/PSD/S2_PDI_Level-1C_Tile_Metadata.xsd">
  <n1:General_Info>
    <TILE_ID metadataLevel="Brief">S2A_OPER_MSI_L1C_TL_MTI__20161111T091803_A007252_T43QBA_N02.04</TILE_ID>
    <DATASTRIP_ID metadataLevel="Standard">S2A_OPER_MSI_L1C_DS_MTI__20161111T091803_S20161111T053350_N02.04</DATASTRIP_ID>
    <DOWNLINK_PRIORITY metadataLevel="Standard">NOMINAL</DOWNLINK_PRIORITY>
    <SENSING_TIME metadataLevel="Standard">2016-11-11T05:33:50.068Z</SENSING_TIME>
    <Archiving_Info metadataLevel="Expertise">
      <ARCHIVING_CENTRE>MTI_</ARCHIVING_CENTRE>
      <ARCHIVING_TIME>2016-11-11T10:53:22.600451Z</ARCHIVING_TIME>
    </Archiving_Info>
  </n1:General_Info>
</n1:Level-1C_Tile_ID>
```

**Code :**

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse(XML_FILE_CONTENT_PASTED_ABOVE)
root = tree.getroot()            
print(root.attrib['xmlns:n1'])
```

**Error :**

```
KeyError: 'xmlns:n1'
```

**Desired output :**

```
https://psd-12.sentinel2.eo.esa.int/PSD/S2_PDI_Level-1C_Tile_Metadata.xsd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A namespace declaration (`xmlns:n1='...'`) looks like an attribute, but it is not part of the `attrib` dictionary of an element.

To get the namespace URI associated with the `n1` prefix, use [`nsmap`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#nsmap):

```
print(root.nsmap["n1"])
```